# ConfigurationManager vs variable

Tags: c#, optimization, configurationmanager

So I've seen a piece of code in our WCF service which reads a value from the config (appsettings) and allocates that value to a variable. That variable is subsequently interrogated to change the outcome of the method call.

The particular WCF call in question is invoked quite a lot. I was considering whether removing the variable and it's allocation and therefore making multiple calls to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seeting"] in it's place would be more performant than the allocating of memory for a new variable to hold the value ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seeting"] on every method call (albeit once per call at the top of the method execution).

This is probably a micro optimization, but the allocation of memory on the heap each execution got me to thinking whether it's quicker to interrogate the NameValueCollection behind AppSettings or allocate memory for marginally cleaner code.

Opinions welcome.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and find out which is more performant?

Comment: I Should do. On this occasion I thought seeking wider opinion might be quicker than benchmarking it, allow me to focus on delivering what's being asked of me. If I find the time I will, and I'll put up the results.

Answer (score 1):

Opinion: Micro optimization is the root of all evil ...

If you find it a problem, try to solve it. Otherwise, I doubt it's really a problem. The only thing is, in order to figure it out, you'll have to spend some time profiling your application. The time you'll spend might be longer than what you'll save.... up to you really.

(having said that, I know how you feel, since I sometime wonder about those issues myself ... I will usually try to kick myself back into productive work though, instead of day dreaming about it ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your problem lies in the ConfigurationManager, because (per MSDN):

`For some sections such as appSettings and connectionStrings, use the AppSettings and ConnectionStrings classes. These members perform read-only operations, use a single cached instance of the configuration, and are multithread aware.` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Being that appsettings are cached, accessing the collection via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["x"] would not be a wasteful operation.